# After forward declaration i can't use other classes in same namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, forward-declaration

I would appreciate some help.

I forward declared class Stub in a namespace.

```
#ifndef SERVERACCESS_HPP
#define SERVERACCESS_HPP

#include <memory>

namespace License {
namespace Grpc {
namespace Testservice{
class Stub;
}}}//namespace License::Grpc::Testservice

namespace grpc {
class Channel;
} //namespace grpc

class AccessToServer final {
    public:
    AccessToServer(const char* serverAdress, const int port);

    private:
    std::shared_ptr<grpc::Channel> ChannelToSever;
    std::unique_ptr<License::Grpc::Testservice::Stub> Stub;
};

#endif //SERVERACCESS_HPP
```

In the source i want to use newStub from the same namespace: But get the error message: no member named 'NewStub' in namespace 'License::Grpc::Testservice'
Without forward declaration it's all fine.

```
#include "serverAcess.hpp"

#include <fmt/format.h>
#include <grpcpp/channel.h>
#include <grpcpp/create_channel.h>
#include <Testservice.grpc.pb.h>

#include <string>


AccessToServer::AccessToServer(const char* serverAddress, const int port) {
    std::string ServerIpAndPortFormatted = fmt::format("{}:{}", serverAddress, port);
    ServerIpAndPortFormatted += ":" + std::to_string(port);

    ChannelToSever = grpc::CreateChannel(ServerIpAndPortFormatted, grpc::InsecureChannelCredentials());
    Stub           = License::Grpc::Testservice::NewStub(ChannelToSever);

    return;
}
```

Comment: Where's `NewStub` declared at?

Comment: It's declared in Header Testservice.grpc.pb.h> under the same namespace. Without a forward declaration and "Testservice.grpc.pb.h>" included in  serverAcess.hpp it compiles fine.

Comment: Is that the only error? Nothing gets printed **before** "no member named 'NewStub' in namespace 'License::Grpc::Testservice'"?

Comment: it's the only error. It doesn't prints any errors before. I really dom't know what happens here. Something seems fishy with my forward declaration of Stub. Because without that  my code compiles without any error

Comment: The devil's in the details, which is why the rules for posting on S.O. include providing the shortest possible actual code to reproduce the problem.  Saying "it's declared in Header Testservice.grpc.pb.h> under the same namespace." is useless - maybe you've got a typo there or something.  If we could trust you hadn't made a mistake then you wouldn't be asking.